# command 'flow.restartClient' not found in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use [flow-for-vscode](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode), but it looks like not working, in fact when I try to use it I get:

`command 'flow.restartClient' not found`

Notice that `./node_modules/.bin/flow` works correctly from my project folder.

I also tried to set `${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/flow` as Path to Flow, but it doesn't work.

Also, disabling Use LSP gives the same result.